# Virtualeve + django + mysql database error

Tags: mysql, django, virtualenv

i am trying to run my django project in virtualeve , but i get this error when login page is loaded

./manage.py runserver 8080

> ERROR ENCOUNTERED  : "DatabaseError at /accounts/login/ (1142, "INSERT
>   command denied to user 'tsepakreadonly'@'122.179.108.95'          for
>   table 'django_session'")"

I cannot find the problem. Any solutions.

Comment: The problem is with your database permissions; reconfirm those. The access rights are not set up correctly.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid thanks , but how do u access the mysql database in virtualeve , i used pip install -r requirements.txt from a existing project folder , sorry i am new

Comment: Use the `mysql` command. virtualenv is only for Python libraries. Your normal system commands will work fine.